# In Linux, how to run Django custom management using crontab?

Tags: django, bash, cron

I have generated a bash script that activates virtaulenv and runs my custom management command in Django. I want to run the bash script every day at midnight.

**Bash Script** :

```
cd ~
cd path_to_virtualenv/
source virtualenv_name/bin/activate
cd path_to_project/
python manage.py custom_command
deactivate
```

When I run this script using `.` or `source` it runs perfectly. I have configured crontab to run this bash script (For testing, I have set execution time per minute). But I am not getting desired output.

**crontab -e**

```
*/1 * * * * source /path_to_bash_script/bash_script_filename
```

Comment: Update your question with actual script name and script path to paint a system file structure image.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add shebang to your shell script (i.e: `#!/bin/bash`, ...)
2. Remove `source` from crontab
3. add an `extension` to your script file.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the script as :

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path_to_virutalenv/bin/activate
python /path_to_project/manage.py custom_command
```

In crontab :

```
*/1 * * * * bash /path_to_bash_script/script.sh
```